# how correctly use ternary operator in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React. I've just started recently and have some kind of knowledge gap in syntax of javascript. I don't know how to write correctly code in order to toggle element condition, from `display: block` to `display: none`. I'm trying to use ternary operator, but I don't know how to do it.

```
 toggleFilters = (e) => {
    this.state.showOn === true ? {e.style.display ? 'block' : 'none'}

    this.setState({
        showOn: !this.state.showOn,
    })
}
```

Comment: `this.state.showOn === true ? {e.style.display ? 'block' : 'none'}` -> `e.style.display = this.state.showOn ? 'block' : 'none'` did you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
{e.style.display  = this.state.showOn === true ? 'block' : 'none'}
```

or

```
{e.style.display  = this.state.showOn ? 'block' : 'none'}
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you wrote won't compile, the ternary operator you used is wrong in:

```
this.state.showOn === true ? {e.style.display ? 'block' : 'none'}
```

Because `:` is expected after the `{}` block, and another thing you are not doing any assignement there, it should be like this:

```
e.style.display = this.state.showOn ? 'block' : 'none';
```

**Note:**

Note that `this.state.showOn === true` can be shortened to `this.state.showOn`, as `this.state.showOn` means that it's not `undefined` and it's `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to do it, is this. 
This says that your e.style.display is block if your shownOn is true else your e.style.display is false.

```
e.style.display = this.state.showOn ? 'block' : 'none'}
```

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator is generally associated with assignment. For example, if we have the following code bit:

```
let a = 'foo';
let conditionA = false;

if ( conditionA ) {
    a = 'bar';
} else {
    a = 'baz';
}
```

You can imagine the ternary operator which will - sort of - implicitly return a value based on a condition. In this case, we need `a` to have a value of `bar` if `conditionA` is `true`, otherwise, `baz`. You can see that we're dealing with assignment here. The ternary way to do this would be:

```
...
a = ( conditionA ) ? 'bar' : 'baz';
...
```

In this case, however, you'd need `conditionA` to be defined previously.

The basic syntax for the ternary operation is:

```
variable = ( condition ) ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

In your specific case, you can go with something like:

```
e.style.display = ( this.state.showOn ) ? 'block' : 'none';
```

As you can extrapolate, we're following the syntax we mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In react, you have state to store properties of the component, in this case, `showOn` is a state.

Your render function reflect this state to the element. In this case, if state showOn is true, you show your element (aka: set display to `block`), if not, you hide your element (aka: set display to `none`)

When you handle event, you change this state. In order to do so, you set `showOn` = invert of current `showOn`

```
toggleFilter = (event) => { 
    this.setState ({
        showOn: !this.state.showOn
    })
}
```

In render function, you reflect this change to your element, now you can use ternary operator

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={({display: this.state.showOn ? 'block' : 'none'})}> 
                Show Me
            </div>
            <button onClick={toggleFilter}>Toggle Filter</button>
    )
}
```